# How to find absolute index() with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

```
<nav>
    <section>
        <aside>
    <div class="findthis">111111</div>
    <div class="findthis">222222</div>
    <div class="findthis">333333</div>  
    <div class="findthis">444444</div>
        </aside>
    </section>
</nav>


$('.findthis').each( function(){
      var index = $(this).index()+1;
      $(this).append(" ( this element = "+index+" )")
});
```

this is working! (http://jsfiddle.net/3c5TZ/)

but.... when i do/insert more HTML-tags like this...

```
<nav>
    <section>
        <aside>
    <div class="findthis">111111</div>
            <h2><h2>
    <div class="findthis">222222</div>
            <span></span>
    <div class="findthis">333333</div>
            <b></b>                          
    <div class="findthis">444444</div>
        </aside>
    </section>
</nav>
```

it fails! (http://jsfiddle.net/3c5TZ/1/)

Any ideas?

Comment: So what index values do you expect in the second instance?

Comment: @amnotiam this is due to the unclosed `h2` element..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please consult the [documentation of `index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/). In your example, jQuery cannot really know what kind of index you are looking for, relative to what?

One way of doing this is providing the selector for `.index()`:

```
$('.findthis').each( function(){
      var index = $(this).index('.findthis')+1;
      $(this).append(" ( this element = "+index+" )")
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3c5TZ/2/)

Another (in this case maybe more effective) way is to run `index()` on the whole collection, and pass the element as a parameter:

```
var $collection = $('.findthis');
$collection.each( function(){
      var index = $collection.index(this)+1;
      $(this).append(" ( this element = "+index+" )")
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3c5TZ/10/)

Answer (score 5):

The index is passed to the `.each()` method you don't have to reinvent the wheel:

```
$('.findthis').each( function(index){
    $(this).append(" ( this element = " + (index + 1) + " )")
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3c5TZ/12/).

Comment: +1 I did not think of the trivial solution :). This answer should be accepted.

Comment: @baz well, the direct question asked about `.index()` method - easy to miss it's inside `.each()`.

Answer (score 3):

You have accidentally nested elements inside each other.

Change this:

```
<h2><h2>
```

to this:

```
<h2></h2>
```

Then it works just fine. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/3c5TZ/14/

Comment: hehehe... I hadn't seen this too!

Comment: Good catch. I'm not sure what the op wanted to achieve. 1,2,3,4 or 1,3,5,7?

Answer (score 1):

use `.index('.findthis')` to constrain the counting only inside the list of `.findthis` items.

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/3c5TZ/5/

*also fixed the missing `</h2>` bug*

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.findthis').each( function(i){
  $(this).append(" ( this element = "+i+" )")
});
```

Try this ...